# How to create a "Basic Page" in Visual Studio 2015 community

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I would like to know if it is possible to make the "Basic Page" in VS 2015 because I bought the Head First C# 3rd Edition book. They use VS 2012 Express which gives the option of creating a "Basic Page" when adding files to the Project. I see that certain codes are written in "Basic Page" that do not show in "Blank Page" code.

I know that things have changed with the new version of VS but I would just like to know if there is a way to create a "Basic Page" or should I use "Blank Page" and enter the code manually? (Please see my image below)

[Adding new item to project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD3YH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what sort of code a "basic page" is supposed to contain, but if you have the code handy, you can paste it into a blank page and save it as a template so you can use it again:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx

You don't need to specify an icon or preview image if you don't want to; a default will be used if you don't.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ekolis.  The "basic page" contains the "back" button and a page title with this custom grid.  I shall be using your link to create my own template if I'll be using the same structure in the future.